# Spring @WebMvcTest with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing

I have a problem when I want to test controllers using @WebMvcTest - on application load I get:

```
...
Field customUserDetailsService in com.test.config.SecurityConfig required a bean of type 'com.test.security.CustomUserDetailsService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.test.security.CustomUserDetailsService' in your configuration.
...
```

Do you have any idea what is problem? Is it good solution to exclude security?

There are classes:

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EmployeeController {

    private final EmployeeService employeeService;

    @GetMapping
    public List<EmployeeDTO> getEmployees() {
        return employeeService.getAllEmployees();
    }
}
```

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = EmployeeController.class)
class EmployeeControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks
    private EmployeeController employeeController;

    @Test
    void getEmployees_Success() throws Exception {
//        mockMvc.perform(get("/employee/all")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The controller which you are using in test have a dependency  `EmployeeService employeeService;`
So in test case add below.

```
@Mock
EmployeeService employeeService;
```

Comment: @InjectMocks should cover that. It's not problem in that - problem is in loading security (CustomUserDetailsService)

Comment: When you put WebMvcTest it only enables controller test. So it may be a problem in your controller. Test it..